# CCmdUI Enable drop down menu, object reference not set

Tags: c++, visual-studio, object, reference

In the code below on the line:

```
p->m_pOther = (CWnd*)GetDlgItem(ID_ENABLE);
```

I am getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
LRESULT MainTestFramework::OnUpdate(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
CCmdUI* p;
p->m_pOther = (CWnd*)GetDlgItem(ID_DUPLICATE);
p->Enable(true);
return 0;
}
```

I am attempting to enable ID_DUPLICATE which is a dropdown menu item.

Comment: As the message indicates, `p` is not set to any instance. It points to some unspecified address. That address almost surely does not contain a valid `CCmdUI` instance.

Comment: Is "CCmdUI* p;" not setting p to CCmdUI?

Comment: `CCmdUI` is a type. It describes a *kind of thing*. That line states that `p` can only point to `CCmdUI` objects, but it doesn't say *which* `CCmdUI` it is pointing to. In fact, it isn't even explicitly stating that it *doesn't* point to an instance, it's simply initialized. It is a good habit to explicitly initialize your pointers with `nullptr` to make sure they have a state.